# Android Failed to find com.android.support

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

i'm trying to install Android android.support libraries from gradle, but i get this error:

```
Error:Failed to find: com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.0

Error:Failed to find: com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3

Error:Failed to find: com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.0

Error:Failed to find: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3
```

My full `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "br.com.halyson.materialdesign"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            zipAlignEnabled true
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources false
            debuggable false
            proguardFiles 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            debuggable true
            proguardFiles 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.5'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.4'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.1.+'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.1.+'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.8.+'
    compile 'com.melnykov:floatingactionbutton:1.1.0'
    compile 'com.github.ksoichiro:android-observablescrollview:1.4.0'
    compile 'com.astuetz:pagerslidingtabstrip:1.0.1'
}
```

i'm installed Android support library and Android support repository from Android SDK manager. how to resolve this problem? or choose other version of this supports?

Comment: Make sure you have all the latest versions of support libraries installed in the SDK Manager.

Comment: @Bidhan whats support libraries name in Android SDK manager? please see this screen shot: http://s6.uplod.ir/i/00606/mjznf3ep7bwz.png

Comment: Inside Extras, do you have **Android Support Repository** and **Android Support Library** installed?

Comment: @BidhanA i'm trying to install, thanks

Comment: Okay tell me how it goes..

Comment: @BidhanA dont resolve problem sir. after install that i get same error. http://s6.uplod.ir/i/00606/khtgwoqnm1ik.png

Comment: Can you edit your post with your full build.gradle file?

Answer (score 0):

Delete *.jar (with error's library) from folder `libs` inside your project. Then clear project. Then build.

Also sure that libraries jar-files exist inside `\\sdk\extras\...` subfolders

Comment: Dont resolve problem sir. i'm trying to install libraries from Gradle, i get `Error:Failed to find: com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.0`  FULL Error:  `Library android-observablescrollview-1.4.0 has broken classes paths:   /home/mahdi/Projects/Material-Example/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.github.ksoichiro/android-observablescrollview/1.4.0/res   /home/mahdi/Projects/Material-Example/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.github.ksoichiro/android-observablescrollview/1.4.0/classes.jar [Fix]`

Comment: Also try temporary disable proguard

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your dependencies to look like this

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.1.1'
```

Comment: i get this error sir: `Error:Failed to find: com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.+` i'm installed support libraries

Comment: Errors are same and i get `Failed to find` message.

Comment: Edited my answer. Try putting specific version like that.

Comment: This is strange. Do this. Remove all 4 compile statements. Now, right click on your Project, then choose **Open Module Settings**. Then, go to **Dependencies** tab, and click on the Green Add button on the right. Now, search for all 4 libraries and then add the appropriate version from the drop down list. See if that works for you.

Comment: Did you Right Click on your project folder on the Left and choose Open Module Settings? Also, after clicking the Green Add button, click on **Library Dependency**, not **Module Dependency**

Comment: You're not getting the option for adding Library Dependencies. There should be an option to do so. I can't figure out what's wrong.